# Identification of asian seal on 2 paintings

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

here is 2 others old asian paintings that I own from which I totally ignore the artist's name and would be happy to know it. I am posting the paintings gradually.

[image]
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Painting 1

Seal, upper-right

> 上下千古
> From the past to the present, spanning heaven and earth

Calligraphy

> 富䝿（貴）玉堂
> Palace of the nobility
>
> 蕙村寫
> Written by 蕙村 (Orchid Village, *artist's [art name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_name)*)

Seal, left, top

> 金炯辰印
> Seal of 金炯辰 (*artist's real name*)

Seal, left, bottom

> 蕙邨（村）
> Orchid Village

---

#### Painting 2

Seal, upper-right

> 丹青即墨
> From Vibrant Colours (*artist's art name*) to inks and paints

Calligraphy

> 松溪疊泉
> Pines, creeks, and springs upon springs
>
> 丹青
> Vibrant Colours

Seal, left

> 丹青
> Vibrant Colours

Comment: Thank you @dROOOze! So, if I understand well, artist's real name of paiting 1 is "Jin Jiongchen" (translated 金炯辰) and for the painting 2 nobody can be identified by name. Am I right?

Comment: @damyp For artist 1, "Jin Jiongchen" would be a Mandarin Chinese pronunciation of the name 金炯辰, but I can't find a Chinese artist going by this name so I don't know if the artist is Chinese. For artist 2, the artist decided to use their art name in the writings you provided - if they showed their real name it's not in the photos.

Comment: Thank you for you explicit answer. :)